# How to make the map auto fit the available div area in full view. Is auto-repeat possible to fill white gaps

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to show the entire world, but my map is very small at the zoom level 0 and 1. As a result it leaves white gaps and looks ugly. 
Is there any way to tell the map to auto-fill the white area with map repeation ? I am using tiled layers.

Projection : 102100
[image]

Comment: Could you add an image of this? Projection type will play a key role here as well

Comment: Changing of projection would also be my best bet. Otherwise, you could change the background color of the map div so that it corresponds to your water color - at least makes it less obvious :D

Comment: look at it .. its disgusting :P

Comment: This isn't possible with the JavaScript API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been told by developers at Esri that it is not a priority for them. Even the 4.0 release can not do it. Looking at Leaflet and Google you would have though its easily doable.

I think its the complexity of events attached to the svg graphics that's a hurdle. More than the map service images itself.